pg java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
When performing query operations on the PG database, occasional socket connection timeouts may be reported. There is a firewall between the business server and the database server. Could this be the cause? Using Durid connection pool
type: com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource
driverClassName: com.highgo.jdbc.Driver
url: jdbc:highgo://ip:port/data?characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&connectTimeout=5&socketTimeout=100
username:
password:
sql-script-encoding: utf-8
initialSize: 30
minIdle: 30
maxActive: 200
# 配置获取连接等待超时的时间
maxWait: 6000
# 配置间隔多久才进行一次检测，检测需要关闭的空闲连接，单位是毫秒
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 60000
# 配置一个连接在池中最小生存的时间，单位是毫秒
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 180000
validationQuery: select version()
testWhileIdle: false
testOnBorrow: true
testOnReturn: false

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
